# PHP, using parent class properties as another type in child class

Tags: php, oop, polymorphism

i got 2 class Node and ChildNode, ChildNode extends Node. There property in parent:

```
class Node {
    protected $discount;
    public function __construct($discount) {
        $this->discount = $discount;
```

and i use it there like integer value, in the ChildNode i need to hold array of integer values

```
class ChildNode extends Node {
    public function __construct(Array $discount) {
        $this->discount = $discount;
```

Is it normal to do like this?

Comment: Why do you need inheritance at all? You certain value has different type in your inheritance tree hence you probably have to override all methods of parent class to work with it. You could build inheritance tree with interfaces and implemnt those by different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with this. If you have multiple classes that will all benefit from a parent class structured this way it makes it easy to add another method or another variable to all of the child classes at once in the future. I also checked to see how PHP handles inheritance since I was not 100% sure on this and also because php will automagically set variables for you if you assign to something like $this->doesnotexistyet = "magic!"; however the below outputs the following...

```
class A {

    protected $d;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->d = "A";
    }

    public function getDP() {
        return $this->d;
    }

}

class B extends A {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->d = "B";
    }

    public function getD() {
        return $this->d;
    }

}

$a = new A();
echo $a->getDP() . PHP_EOL;

$b = new B();
echo $b->getD() . PHP_EOL;
echo $b->getDP() . PHP_EOL;

var_dump($a , $b);
```

Output.

```
A
B
B
object(A)#1 (1) {
  ["d":protected]=>
  string(1) "A"
}
object(B)#2 (1) {
  ["d":protected]=>
  string(1) "B"
}
```

This was more for me than anything but thought I would add it if it helps others who come across this.